# Create a table with defined levels in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of actual values (factor variables) `a a a b b c c b c b c c ...`

I have a vector of predict values `a b b a ...`

I want to create a confusion matrix `t = table (actual, predict)`

If I print `t`, it will looks like:

```
   a b c
a  4 3 1
b 1  5 2
c  3 1 8
```

However, I want to print it as

```
    b c a
b   8 2 3
c   2 3 4
a   1 2 3
```

(i.e, I want to change the order of row and columns, but keep it as a confusion matrix)

How could I do that in R?

Comment: It looks like you want to change both the order of the row and columns and their labels, is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could change/convert the columns to `factor` with levels specified.

```
actual <- factor(actual, levels=c('b', 'c', 'a'))
predict <- factor( predict, levels = c('b', 'c', 'a'))
table(actual, predict)
#        predict
#actual b c a
#     b 0 1 4
#     c 3 2 2
#     a 2 3 3
```

---

Or we can use `row/column` indexing

```
table(actual, predict)[c('b','c','a'), c('b', 'c', 'a')]
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 actual <- sample(letters[1:3], 20, replace=TRUE)
 predict <- sample(letters[1:3], 20, replace=TRUE)
```